# Windows10がフリーズした際のエラーログを確認したいのですが

Tags: windows

**現状**
・不定期で、Windows10のデスクトップパソコンがフリーズします
・その都度、再起動しています

---

**やりたいこと**
・Windows10でフリーズした場合、強制終了後、普通に起動させるのですが、その際エラーログを確認したい

---

**質問**
・Windows10でフリーズした際のエラーログを確認する方法はありますか？
・タスクスケジューラーで、フリーズした際のエラー内容を記録するタスクを作成することはできますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windowsキー + S で検索欄がでると思うので、そこで「イベント ビューアー」と打ってみてください。
イベントビューアーを起動して、Windows ログ → システム の所にシステム的なエラーならメッセージが出てるかと思います。